# Change content between vertical line in Rust

Tags: rust, neovim

In Neovim, I usually do a "change inside" action - key: `ci + <char>` - to change the content inside some brackets or quotations. But it does not work for the vertical line in a rust closure.

```
    // ---------------- v cursor here ---------
    let spawn_worker = |nonce: u32| {
        let tx = nonce_tx.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            // Do the CPU work
            let _ = make_block(nonce).hash();

            // Send the result
            let _ = tx.send(());
        })
    };
```

For example, I put the cursor here and press `ci + |` but it does not work.

Does anyone know the most intuitive way to do it without selecting the content for closures in Rust?

Comment: Can't directly answer your question, but if your cursor's _there_ (immediately after the opening `|`), would `ct|` work for you?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. It works if I put the cursor right after the opening `|`. I guess it works like "change up to" `|`. It does not work when my cursor some where after, only from the cursor up to the next `|`.